# Find the formula to get $0$ or $1$ when input is greater than a threshold

Tags: absolute-value

- $x \geq m, f(x) = 1$
- $x <m, f(x) = 0$

My best result so far is :

$$f(x) = 
\frac{ x-m + \left| x-m \right|}{2\left| x-m \right|} $$

But when $x = m$, it is invalid...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 4):

Let sgn be the sign function (present in most programming languages). Then this function should do it for a threshold $m$: $$\frac{\mathrm{sgn}(x-m)+1}{2}$$

Depending on the implementation of sgn, this gives $1/2$ for $x=m$. If you want it to output $1$ instead, then use $$\mathrm{ceil}((\mathrm{sgn}(x-m)+1)/2)$$

Comment: Tongue in cheek: $(\frac{d}{dx}|x-m|+1)/2$

Comment: @Chrystomath, what would be the correct way to say what the OP meant? I mean the proper wording for "pure math way"

Comment: @user675453 I don't see a difference between pure math and programming. They're just different ways of expressing functions. Or do you mean notation? The step function comes with a name: the Heaviside function, so perhaps $H(x-m)$.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with :

$$f(x) = \operatorname{ceil}\left(
\frac{ x-m + \left| x-m \right|}{2\left| x-m \right| + 1}\right)$$

Not very mathematic but usable for programming.

@Chrystomath's solution is somewhat better/shorter in term of programming.