# What formula returns either a 1 or 0 depending on whether you input any non-zero integer or 0 respectively?

Tags: functions

Using just basic math that you can write on paper (ie, not any software specific tools/features/algorithms) can you help me think of a formula that will do this?

I need to input an integer and return either a 1 or a 0. Input of 0 should return 0, and any other input should always return 1.

I realize for coding purposes I could just use an "if" statement that always returns 1 or 0 depending on whether n == 0.

Comment: Already been asked, I guess https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3743361/675453

Comment: $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x=0 \\ 1 & x\neq0 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try $$f(x)=|\text{sgn} (x) |$$

If you feel like making use of the sign function is still ‘cheating’, try this instead: $$f(x) = \bigg\lceil \frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\bigg \rceil$$
Another classic: $$f(x)=\lceil \sin^2x \rceil$$

Comment: How do you get $f(0) = 0$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin $\text{sgn}(0)$ is defined to be $0$. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that.

Comment: That will return all sorts of decimals though. I want always 1 or 0.

Comment: @BenMora The output of sgn(x) is always $-1,0$ or $1$, and the absolute turns the $-1$ to a $1$.

Comment: Maybe I don't know what "sgn" means then. I didn't think it was the same as "sin" but saw a different question somewhere that seemed to be using "sgn" and "sin" interchangeably. I have to assume I am wrong at this point, because the sin of 1 is 0.017 or 0.84 depending on whether deg or rad.

Comment: @BenMora Yep. See the link for the definition of sgn(x), then. I’ve also added another function you could use, if you don’t like the sign function.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've learned more than I set out to!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is
$$
f(x) = \min(1, |x|)
$$

Comment: eh, yes, but "min" is more of a programming thing isn't it? I'm thinking what a highschool level student could come up with based on what they learn in math classes, with no knowledge of CS required.

Comment: I disagree. min is a very elementary function that can be explained to any 6-year kid. It was used long before programming even existed.

Comment: But how do you _do_ min? Obviously I could use my brain to instantly know the smaller of any two numbers, but how would you prove it? (this might be a not-so-relevant question more for the fun of thinking about it at this point.

Comment: I just feel like using "min" is almost the same as saying that the formula to answer the question _is_ the question itself. Q: How do you get a 0 or a 1 when given a 0 or a different integer? A: You just pick a 0 when given 0, and pick 1 when given a different integer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to computer scientists.

For any positive number:

```
f(x) = min(1, ceiling(x))
```

Returns `0` if `x == 0` and `1` if `x > 0`.

For any number:

```
f(x) = min(1, ceiling(abs(x)))
```

Returns `0` if `x == 0` and `1` if `x != 0`.

Comment: Please don't answer old questions that already have answers. That bumps them to the head of the active queue and wastes time for folks like me who follow that queue.

Comment: I feel my answer is valuable. It is much more efficient than the proposed answers for implementation on a computer.